# Convert to dot notation

Tags: c#, linq

How can I convert this query to use Extension Methods?

```
var x = from Prods n in Cat.Prod.GetAllProds()
        orderby n.Name
        select new
        {
            Name = n.Name,                        
            Cost = n.Cost
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

Its called Lambda notation.

```
var x = Cat.Prod.GetAllProds().OrderBy(n=>n.Name).Select(n=>new {n.Name,n.Cost});
```

Note that you do not need to provide a name for each column you are selecting if that name is the same as the column name:

```
new
{
    Name = n.Name,                        
    Cost = n.Cost
});
```

Is exactly the same as:

```
new
{
    n.Name,                        
    n.Cost
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple in this case:

```
var x = Cat.Prod
           .GetAllProds()
           .OrderBy(n => n.Name)
           .Select(n => new
                        {
                           Name = n.Name,                        
                           Cost = n.Cost
                        });
```

For more information, I suggest reading  [How query expressions work - Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx).